# Creating a temp table in stored procedure with SQL and Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a stored procedure which gets the session variables
in snowflake. I want to store these variables in a temporary table
so then I can use it later on.

My logic works but I am unable to write the syntax correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_CONTEXT()
  RETURNS VARCHAR
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  COMMENT = 'Saves current database and current schema in an array'
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
  AS
  $$
    var arr_context = [];
    v_sqlCode = "SELECT CURRENT_DATABASE(), CURRENT_SCHEMA()";
   
    try{
        var sqlStmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText :  v_sqlCode});
        var sqlRS = sqlStmt.execute();
    }catch(err){
        errMessage =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
        errMessage += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
        errMessage += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt;  
        throw 'Encountered error in executing v_sqlCode. \n' + errMessage;
       }
     
    var v_sqlCode = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_HOLDER (DATABASE VARCHAR(16777216), SCHEMA VARCHAR(16777216))";
   
        try{
        var sqlStmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText :  v_sqlCode});
        var sqlRS2 = sqlStmt.execute();
    }catch(err){
        errMessage =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
        errMessage += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
        errMessage += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt;  
        throw 'Encountered error in executing v_sqlCode. \n' + errMessage;
       }
       
     
    v_sqlCode = "INSERT INTO TEMP_HOLDER(DATABASE, SCHEMA)
                 VALUES(" + sqlRS.getColumnValue(1) + ", "+sqlRS.getColumnValue(2)+")";
                 
   
          try{
        var sqlStmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText :  v_sqlCode});
        var sqlRS = sqlStmt.execute();
    }catch(err){
        errMessage =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
        errMessage += "\n  Message: " + err.message + sqlRS.getColumnValue(1);
        errMessage += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt;  
        throw 'Encountered error in executing v_sqlCode. \n' + errMessage;
       }
   
    $$;
   
  CALL  GET_CONTEXT();
```

Answer (score 0):

This simplifies it. It also changes the column names from DATABASE and SCHEMA, which are reserved keywords, by prefixing with THE_ such as THE_DATABASE.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_CONTEXT()
  RETURNS VARCHAR
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  COMMENT = 'Saves current database and current schema in an array'
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
  AS
  $$

    let v_sqlCode = "create or replace temp table TEMP_HOLDER as select current_database() as THE_DATABASE,current_schema() as THE_SCHEMA";
    
    try{
        var sqlStmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText :  v_sqlCode});
        var sqlRS = sqlStmt.execute();
    }catch(err){
        errMessage =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
        errMessage += "\n  Message: " + err.message + sqlRS.getColumnValue(1);
        errMessage += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt;  
        throw 'Encountered error in executing v_sqlCode. \n' + errMessage;
       }

    $$;
```